# Excel cell format by ACE.OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, aceoledb

I have the following code which I update a cell in an Excel file, but does not follow the format I have in my cell:

```
string cad = @" Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
             @"Data Source=" + 
             Server.MapPath("~/SVG/" + filenameexport + ".xlsx;") + 
             @"Extended Properties=" + '"' + "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO" + '"';
try
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cad))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = @"UPDATE [Cost Planning$] SET F9= ? WHERE F1 = 'Category'";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToDateTime("2014/07/01"));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

As I can make it respect me the cell format?

This code line, where I add in my code?

```
((Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Range("A1")).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
```

Because the link that send is when generate Excel file of 0, and my Excel file this created.

Comment: What is the correct format?

Comment: The Custom "yyyy-mmm" would correct format

Answer (score 1):

You can format Excel column using `NumberFormat` property (as discussed in [How to make correct date format when writing data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310800/how-to-make-correct-date-format-when-writing-data-to-excel) ). For example, to set it to date format like the following:

```
((Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Range("A1")).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
```