# Convert excel column from General to Date in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a `nvarchar(50)` column in SQL which is of format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I am trying to import this data in excel using SSIS. In ssis package, I am creating a column Date_1 with datatype Date in Execute SQL task (Since .xlsx file needs to be created dynamically) and in my data flow task I am converting Date_1 to date(`DT_DATE`). But after data migration when I check my file column Date_1 is of General data type and not Date. Can someone help me how to convert General column to Date

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down list you are showing in the Microsoft Excel interface is not related to the data type it is the `Number Format` property which is used to change the way the value is shown in Excel.

- [Available number formats](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/available-number-formats-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2)

To change this property you need to use `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` library within a Script Task and change the `Excel.Range.NumberFormat` property. As example:

```
Range rg = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[1,1];
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

**References**

- [How to make correct date format when writing data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310800/how-to-make-correct-date-format-when-writing-data-to-excel)
- [How to: Specify Number or Date Format for Cell Content](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/12273/Spreadsheet-Document-API/Examples/Formatting-Cells/How-to-Specify-Number-or-Date-Format-for-Cell-Content)