# C# Excel changes the date format when I write a date in a worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using this code to write a date on a cell

```
mWSheet1.Cells[row, 7] = "01/12/2019";
```

but when I open the Excel file, it saves "12/01/2019".
How can I solve it?

Comment: Try to format the cell like this: `mWSheet1.Cells[row, 7].NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";`

Comment: Probably duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310800/how-to-make-correct-date-format-when-writing-data-to-excel

Comment: I would not use ambiguous date formats - is that Jan 12th or Dec 1st? Use `DateTime.ToOADate()` to specify the date _value_ and let Excel worry about the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried passing your date using the Format class? Note that passing the ' in before the value will tell excel to format it as text and it shouldn't try and do its own formatting.

```
mWSheet1.Cells[row , 7] = "'" + Format("01/12/2019", "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: this will work, but sorting will be done on string - not on date