# Local Time Format in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using c# to import same data in Excel and on of the cell in each row has date time

```
var dataToImportToExcel= new object[1048576, 10] //Array of data
foreach(...)
{
...
     dataToImportToExcel[row, columnIndex++] = UnixTime.LocalTimeToDateTime(time)
...
}
```

Here UnixTime is defined as `Epoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp)`

After creating the above variable it's passed to current worksheet

```
var writeRange = currentWorkSheet.Range[i, j];
writeRange.Value2 = dataToImportToExcel;
```

Excel is showing  date time format as `02/05/2021 06:04:37.000 pm` instead of `5/2/2021  6:04:35 pm`, here later on is the local date time format. Even if I change local date time format in machine it always uses first format only.
While debugging I can see in the IDE that date format is correctly showing in variable `dataToImportToExcel`

Comment: I do not think that `UnixTime` is standard available in Excel, how did you define it? My guess is that it returns a string, and not a datetime.

Comment: Sorry it's defined as `Epoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks your Excel understood that you wrote a DateTime value into the cell.
It's format is not defined by the value but by the formatting information set on Cell or Range. Looking into [How to make correct date format when writing data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310800/how-to-make-correct-date-format-when-writing-data-to-excel) topic you should set it like this:

```csharp
Range rg = (Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Cells[1,1];
// Instead of "MM/DD/YYYY" you may use a format specifier appropriate for your needs.
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
```

This will format the entire column in the same way. Following the topic above you will find other examples like setting only one cell's format.

Comment: I don't want to restrict to specific format, if local format changes I want to use that.
I want to show date time format same as local date time format selected in machine